# iOS CoreData NSFetchedResultsController sections and sorting

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I currently have a CoreData entity that has a `name` and `date` attributes, and I would like to create a `NSFetchedResultsController` that returns the results sectioned by `name` sorted by `date` descending (both the sections and its contents), and if possible, only one entry per section. I prefer not to use `NSDictionaryResultType`.

Lets say I have the following entries:

```
Name | Date (year/month/day)
-----+----------------------
Anne | 2014/01/16
John | 2014/01/17
John | 2014/01/15
Nick | 2014/01/13
Nick | 2014/01/10
```

For the above data I wish to obtain only the following results:

```
Section | Entry Date
--------+-----------
John    | 2014/01/17
Anne    | 2014/01/16
Nick    | 2014/01/13
```

How do I create the `NSFetchedResultsController`to obtain only the data and in the order listed above?

---

As of now I have the following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"my predicate" argumentArray:...]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:moc
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"name"
                                                   cacheName:nil];
```

The above code sections the data by `name`, but each section doesn't have its entries sorted by `date`AND it has entries that are not from that `name`!

The result that I want is the table showing unique `name` sorted by `date` like showed in the beginning of the post.

**Update:** I've been unable to do this, so I switched to result type dictionary and used group by for now, I will leave the question open in the hopes someone knows how to do it.

Comment: will need 2 FRC's, one for date which you have and the other with name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of some code, in regards to my comment

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityThingO"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptorDate , sortDescriptorName];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                managedObjectContext:context
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:@"date"
                                                                           cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: The main issue is the sorting I want for the name (section) is based on the most recent entry for that user and not by the name itself, in my example John has the most recent entry so the first section would be his not Anne's

Comment: Ok, yeah not sure how you can do this. Might need to put the results in an array and then re sort with, sortedArrayUsingComparator, then populate the table. But then who knows what will happen with the sections. If you only want one item in every section, I wouldn't even bother with sections. Just do some basic cell design that gives a similar effect, then you just sort by date, and set your cells "make shift" header to the entity name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (that I am aware of) to limit each section to one result in the NSFetchedResultsController.

But, you might not have to do this. You could probably get away with not displaying everything that is not in the first section.

Also, you should be aware that you should not section the request by using any other key than the key used in the primary sort descriptor

---

If you are using this with a tableView you could try something like this:

FRC creation

```
NSSortDescriptor *sdName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sdDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
// sort by name, then sort by date
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sdName, sdDate]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:moc
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"name"
                                               cacheName:nil];

// fetch...
```

and the tableViewDataSource:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [self fetchedResultsController];
    return [fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1; // only display one result for each section
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [self fetchedResultsController];
    YourObject *object = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ... configure cell ...
```

Depending on how many objects you have per person this might not be feasible. If there are a lot of entries you won't display I would recommend to normalize the core data model. E.g.:

[image]

You then would display a list of Persons. But maybe this normalization would be a good idea regardless of the number of objects per name. Fetching more objects than are displayed smells fishy to me.

Comment: I have considered the approach of only displaying the first element of each section, the main issue is the sorting I want for the name (section) is based on the most recent entry for that user and not by the name itself, in my example John has the most recent entry so the first section would be his not Anne's